# Problem with stderr redirecting non error messages

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stderr

The `adduser` command automatically asks to add a password. The error messages of the `adduser` command gets redirected to the file `felmedelande.txt` which works perfectly fine. But it also redirect the password adding part. The user gets created but I never get to set the password since it somehow is seen as an stderr which I really dont understand. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Here is the code segment I'm talking about:

```
sudo adduser --quiet --home /home/$USER_NAME --shell /bin/bash -gecos "$FULL_NAME" $USER_NAME 2>/home/gina/Projekt_DVA249/felmedelande.txt
```

Comment: That's intentional. Prompts are often written to `stderr` instead of `stdout` so that you'll see them if you're redirecting output.

Comment: I don't think there's any way around it.

Comment: If you just want a record, you might just try `sudo adduser ... 2>&1 | tee /p/a/t/h/foo.txt`

Comment: okay thank you for the help! I'll have to find another way then since I need to be able to type in the password :)